# Custom adapter crash my app (NullPointerException) I'v tried every thing?

Tags: java, android

I have been unable to fix this error; I even created a new project and I get the same result (NullPointerException)

My adapter class:

```
public class ContactAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<ContactsObject>{

    private  Context context; 
    private  List<ContactsObject> contactslist;   
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<ContactsObject> list){

        super(context,R.layout.ctninforow,list); 

        this.context=context;
        this.contactslist=list;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{ 
        TextView tvname,tvemail,tvphone;

        public ViewHolder(View v){
            TextView tvname=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnname);
            TextView tvemail=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnemail);     
            TextView tvphone=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnphone);    
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ViewHolder myholder=null;

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ctninforow,parent,false);

            myholder=new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(myholder); 
        }else{
            myholder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

//  error goes here 

        myholder.tvname.setText(contactslist.get(position).getName());
        myholder.tvemail.setText(contactslist.get(position).getEmail());      
        myholder.tvphone.setText(contactslist.get(position).getPhone());

        return convertView;     
    }
}
```

and this is my XML file for the ctninforow layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/ctnname"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/ctnemail"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/ctnphone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my logcat :

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.mohammedriyadh.backendless1, PID: 2128
java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                               at com.example.mriyadh.backendlessdemo.ContactAdapter.getView(ContactAdapter.java:69)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
```

Comment: If you test hardcoded datas like 'test' in setText setter does it throw an exception ? Just to know if the problems come from the contactslist or the View holder

Comment: Could you post the entire error from logcat please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some modification in your code and it works perfectly

```
public ViewHolder(View v) {
    TextView tvname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnname);
    TextView tvemail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnemail);
    TextView tvphone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnphone);
}
```

into

```
public ViewHolder(View v) {
    tvname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnname);
    tvemail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnemail);
    tvphone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnphone);
}
```

also

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ctninforow, parent, false);
```

into

```
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.ctninforow,parent,false);
```

So the complete code is

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactsObject> {
    private Context context;
    private List<ContactsObject> contactslist;
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactsObject> list) {
        // super(context,R.layout.ctninforow,list);
        super(context, 0, list);
        // super(context, 0, users);
        this.context = context;
        this.contactslist = list;
    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvname, tvemail, tvphone;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            tvname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnname);
            tvemail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnemail);
            tvphone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ctnphone);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder myholder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ctninforow, parent, false);
            myholder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(myholder);
        } else {
            myholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        myholder.tvname.setText(contactslist.get(position).name);
        myholder.tvemail.setText(contactslist.get(position).email);
        myholder.tvphone.setText(contactslist.get(position).phone);
        return convertView;
}}
```

In MainActivity's onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    assert b1 != null;
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ContactsObject newUser2 = new ContactsObject("user1", "user1@gmail.com", "5145789076" );
            adapter.add(newUser2);
        }
    });

    arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<ContactsObject>();
    ContactsObject user2 = new ContactsObject("user2", "user2@gmail.com", "5145789076" );
    arrayOfUsers.add(user2);
    adapter = new ContactAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
    ListView  listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: The `LayoutInflater.from` change wasn't necessary. That method calls the other way that was already there.

Comment: thanks man, its my mistake the definition of the text views was locally  inside the view holder :) but now i had another issue !! my list view display only the last 10 items from the DB while i inserted more than 20 !!!  (I'm using Backendless as baas)

Answer (score 0):

I think the crash has the following reasons:

- when you set text (or some data) to your viewholder, you load the data from `List<ContactsObject> contactslist;`
- in Adapter constructor, you may passed the null object.

Solution: check the data that you pass into the adapter or check it before set data in your viewholder `if(contactslist.get(position) != null)`.

Comment: thanks for your time my friend the issue was with the defintion of the text views inside the view holder